# how can I redirect a url to another url?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

MY application url is : http://219.41.192.244:8080/KanaApp/login   - it will take user to login page

Login is the first page then only user can access the application.

But if user put this url - http://219.41.192.244:8080/KanaApp , it's redirecting to http://219.41.192.244:8080/KanaApp/#/home and taking user to the home page without login. How can I prevent this and make the login page mandatory?

whenever user put this url http://219.41.192.244:8080/KanaApp, I want redirect to http://219.41.192.244:8080/KanaApp/login url, can someone help me here please.

Spring boot application:
I have set the context path  here 
server.contextPath=/KanaApp

and in front end angular

```
    SecurityConfig class:

    .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/forgotPassword").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/setForgotPassword").permitAll()
         .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(handler)
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
```

Comment: Use a guard in your Angular application to redirect users to the login page when they are not logged in. https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: Thanks Berk, can we make it from backend side....in spring boot?

Comment: Normally you wouldn’t expect a user to send a request to your backend, so you add an authorization token to your frontend request and check for authorized request in your spring security configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are missing is a proper security configuration.
If you want your user to be connected, then you must force your user to be. Meaning that you must allow requests only to authenticated user.
You will find a lot of guide on how doing it [spring example here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

What you must do is register a class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, and define which part of your application are secured.
For example:

```
.antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Meaning all uris in /public/... would be allowed for everyone, so you won't have to login to go there, and any others needs to be logged to go there.

As you have a login page, a basic way to force users to go there is to implement spring form login (specified in more depth in the link before). This is the part doing the job

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.permitAll()
```

Declaring spring security form login, all request that must be authenticated will be redirected to the page specified here. You can of course customize this page as you like ([an example from spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#configuring-a-custom-login-page)).

Comment: the same thing I have implemented in my SecurityConfiguration class. I have edit the question and added the code. Please have a check